# jQuery : sum number for table football

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm not good in English. What wrong with my text ^^ sorry :)

I have data in my table football.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ctheidea/7x7MZ/)

I am having trouble building a function to calculate all rows in the table. When the page finishes loading or click row for edit value in textfiled. jQuery will be calculate auto.

GP = Game Played = HOME(W+D+L) + AWAY(W+D+L)

Summary

W = HOME_W + AWAY_W

D = HOME_D + AWAY_D

L = HOME_L + AWAY_L

F = HOME_F + AWAY_F

A = HOME_A + AWAY_A

GD = Summary(F) - Summary(A)

HTML

```
<table id="table-pts">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
        <th colspan="5">HOME</th>
        <th colspan="5">AWAY</th>
        <th colspan="5">SUMMARY</th>
        <th colspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Pos</th>
        <th class="team">Team</th>
        <th>GP</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>W</th>
        <th>D</th>
        <th>L</th>
        <th>F</th>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>GD</th>
        <th>Pts</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <tr id="1" class="edit_tr">
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">
            &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td><span id="summary_GP_1"></span></td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_w_1" class="text">1</span>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="editbox" id="home_w_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_d_1" class="text">3</span>
                <input type="text" value="3" class="editbox" id="home_d_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_l_1" class="text">2</span>
                <input type="text" value="2" class="editbox" id="home_l_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_f_1" class="text">4</span>
                <input type="text" value="4" class="editbox" id="home_f_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_a_1" class="text">76</span>
                <input type="text" value="76" class="editbox" id="home_a_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_w_1" class="text">8</span>
                <input type="text" value="8" class="editbox" id="away_w_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_d_1" class="text">9</span>
                <input type="text" value="9" class="editbox" id="away_d_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_l_1" class="text">10</span>
                <input type="text" value="10" class="editbox" id="away_l_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_f_1" class="text">11</span>
                <input type="text" value="11" class="editbox" id="away_f_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_a_1" class="text">12</span>
                <input type="text" value="12" class="editbox" id="away_a_input_1"/>
            </td>
            <td><span id="summary_w_1" ></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_d_1" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_l_1" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_f_1" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_a_1" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_GD_1" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_Pts_1" class="text"></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="2" class="edit_tr">
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">
            &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td><span id="summary_GP_2"></span></td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_w_2" class="text">1</span>
                <input type="text" value="1" class="editbox" id="home_w_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_d_2" class="text">3</span>
                <input type="text" value="3" class="editbox" id="home_d_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_l_2" class="text">2</span>
                <input type="text" value="2" class="editbox" id="home_l_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_f_2" class="text">4</span>
                <input type="text" value="4" class="editbox" id="home_f_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="home_a_2" class="text">76</span>
                <input type="text" value="76" class="editbox" id="home_a_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_w_2" class="text">8</span>
                <input type="text" value="8" class="editbox" id="away_w_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_d_2" class="text">9</span>
                <input type="text" value="9" class="editbox" id="away_d_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_l_2" class="text">10</span>
                <input type="text" value="10" class="editbox" id="away_l_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_f_2" class="text">11</span>
                <input type="text" value="11" class="editbox" id="away_f_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span id="away_a_2" class="text">12</span>
                <input type="text" value="12" class="editbox" id="away_a_input_2"/>
            </td>
            <td><span id="summary_w_2" ></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_d_2" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_l_2" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_f_2" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_a_2" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_GD_2" class="text"></span></td>
            <td><span id="summary_Pts_2" class="text"></span></td>
        </tr>    
</tbody>
```

JQUERY

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".edit_tr").click(function(){
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#home_w_"+ID).hide();
        $("#home_d_"+ID).hide();
        $("#home_l_"+ID).hide();
        $("#home_f_"+ID).hide();
        $("#home_a_"+ID).hide();
        $("#away_w_"+ID).hide();
        $("#away_d_"+ID).hide();
        $("#away_l_"+ID).hide();
        $("#away_f_"+ID).hide();
        $("#away_a_"+ID).hide();

        $("#home_w_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#home_d_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#home_l_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#home_f_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#home_a_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#away_w_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#away_d_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#away_l_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#away_f_input_"+ID).show();
        $("#away_a_input_"+ID).show();
    }).change(function(){

        // calculate point in table football
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var home_w = parseInt($("#home_w_input_"+ID).val());
        var home_d = parseInt($("#home_d_input_"+ID).val());
        var home_l = parseInt($("#home_l_input_"+ID).val());
        var home_f = parseInt($("#home_f_input_"+ID).val());
        var home_a = parseInt($("#home_a_input_"+ID).val());
        var away_w = parseInt($("#away_w_input_"+ID).val());
        var away_d = parseInt($("#away_d_input_"+ID).val());
        var away_l = parseInt($("#away_l_input_"+ID).val());
        var away_f = parseInt($("#away_f_input_"+ID).val());
        var away_a = parseInt($("#away_a_input_"+ID).val());

        var summaryW = home_w + away_w;
        var summaryD = home_d + away_d;
        var summaryL = home_l + away_l;
        var summaryF = home_f + away_f;
        var summaryA = home_a + away_a;
        var summaryGD = summaryF + summaryA;
        var summaryPts = summaryW * 3 +summaryD * 1;
        var summaryGP = summaryW + summaryD + summaryL;



       /* var dataString = 'id='+ ID + '&home_w='+ home_w + '&home_d='+ home_d + '&home_l='+ home_l + '&home_f='+ home_f + '&home_a='+ home_a + '&away_w='+ away_w + '&away_d='+ away_d + '&away_l='+ away_l + '&away_f='+ away_f + '&away_a='+ away_a + '&action=edit_pts';
        $("#home_w_"+ID).html('<img src="load.gif"/>');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "table_pts_action_ajax.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html)
            {*/

        // live update in my table football
                $("#home_w_"+ID).html(home_w);
                $("#home_d_"+ID).html(home_d);
                $("#home_l_"+ID).html(home_l);   
                $("#home_f_"+ID).html(home_f);
                $("#home_a_"+ID).html(home_a);
                $("#away_w_"+ID).html(away_w);
                $("#away_d_"+ID).html(away_d);
                $("#away_l_"+ID).html(away_l);
                $("#away_f_"+ID).html(away_f);
                $("#away_a_"+ID).html(away_a);

                $("#summary_w_"+ID).html(summaryW);
                $("#summary_d_"+ID).html(summaryD);
                $("#summary_l_"+ID).html(summaryL);
                $("#summary_f_"+ID).html(summaryF);
                $("#summary_a_"+ID).html(summaryA);
                $("#summary_GD_"+ID).html(summaryGD);
                $("#summary_Pts_"+ID).html(summaryPts);
                $("#summary_GP_"+ID).html(summaryGP);


         //   }
      //  });  
    });

    $("#table-pts tbody tr").each(function(){

        // page is load finish.. calculate point in table football
        var ID = $(this).attr('id');
        var txtHomeW = parseInt($("#home_w_"+ID).text());
        var txtHomeD = parseInt($("#home_d_"+ID).text());
        var txtHomeL = parseInt($("#home_l_"+ID).text());
        var txtHomeF = parseInt($("#home_f_"+ID).text());
        var txtHomeA = parseInt($("#home_a_"+ID).text());
        var txtAwayW = parseInt($("#away_w_"+ID).text());
        var txtAwayD = parseInt($("#away_d_"+ID).text());
        var txtAwayL = parseInt($("#away_l_"+ID).text());
        var txtAwayF = parseInt($("#away_f_"+ID).text());
        var txtAwayA = parseInt($("#away_a_"+ID).text()); 

        var summaryW = parseInt(txtHomeW+txtAwayW);
        var summaryD = parseInt(txtHomeD+txtAwayD);
        var summaryL = parseInt(txtHomeL+txtAwayL);
        var summaryF = parseInt(txtHomeF+txtAwayF);
        var summaryA = parseInt(txtHomeA+txtAwayA);
        var summaryGD = parseInt(summaryF-+summaryA);
        var summaryPts = parseInt(summaryW * 3 + summaryD * 1);
        var summaryGP = parseInt(summaryW + summaryD + summaryL);

        $(this).find("#summary_w_"+ID).text(summaryW);
        $(this).find("#summary_d_"+ID).text(summaryD);
        $(this).find("#summary_l_"+ID).text(summaryL);
        $(this).find("#summary_f_"+ID).text(summaryF);
        $(this).find("#summary_a_"+ID).text(summaryA);
        $(this).find("#summary_GD_"+ID).text(summaryGD);
        $(this).find("#summary_Pts_"+ID).text(summaryPts);
        $(this).find("#summary_GP_"+ID).text(summaryGP);

    });



    // Edit input box click action
    $(".editbox").mouseup(function(){
        return false
    });

    // Outside click action
    $(document).mouseup(function(){
        $(".editbox").hide();
        $(".text").show();
    });
});​
```

CSS

```
    #table-pts{
    color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
#table-pts tbody tr{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddcdc;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
#table-pts tbody td{
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 5px 0;
}

#table-pts thead tr th{
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: #233825;
    color: #FFF;
    border-left: 1px solid #CCC;

    width: 30px;
}
#table-pts .table-team{
    width: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 3px 7px 3px 7px;
}
#table-pts .editbox{
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}

#table-pts .odd{background: #fafafa;}
.table-hl
{
    width: 70px;
}
#table-pts input{
    width: 20px;
}​
```

​

Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what your problem is but consider using
`var row = $(this);
 row.find('span').hide();
 row.find('input').show();` instead of `var ID = $(this).attr('id');
            $("#home_w_"+ID).hide();
            $("#home_d_"+ID).hide();
            $("#home_l_"+ID).hide();
            $("#home_f_"+ID).hide();
..`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though i could not get your problem statement exactly, But you can get the sum of columns like this way.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){

        var sum = 0;
           jQuery('.text').each(function(){
              sum += parseInt(jQuery(this).text());   
            });
           console.log(sum);

  });
```

If you want to get sum of both row in one var, then use above code.
Otherwise, if you want seperate sum for both row, assign a different class to 2nd row elements as you have assigned 'test' class in both row right now.
After changing class name, use same code for that class.
You can use that code on edit click or change event as well.

Comment: Sorry.I need to get sum of row.  EX: Pos 1 -> Home_W + HOME_D + HOME_L + AWAY_W + AWAY_L + AWAY_D =  GP is column 3 in 1 Pos.

Comment: You have edited your question , so I'll edit my answer too now as per your problem statement:)

Answer (score 0):

just another solution:

```
var tot = 0;       
 $('tbody tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.text').each(function(){
        tot += parseInt($(this).text());   
    });
    alert(tot);
    tot = 0;
});
```

sum salt element:

```
var sum, i, k;       
 $('tbody tr').each(function() {

     k = ($(this).find('.text').length / 2);

     for(i = 0; i < ($(this).find('.text').length / 2); i++){

         sum = parseInt($(this).find('.text').eq(i).text()) + parseInt($(this).find('.text').eq(k).text());                    
         k++;
         alert(sum);       
     }

});
```

Comment: Thank you Bros. ^^  I will be try it.

Comment: @TumCtheidea view the edited answer, this sum element in td by salt